# Vapor connect to SQLite Database

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to setup a Vapor 3 project with SQLite.
In the `configure.swift` file, I have the following setup related to sqlite:

```
try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())

...

// Get the root directory of the project
// I have verified that the file is present at this path
let path = DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir + "db_name.db"
let sqlite: SQLiteDatabase
do {
    sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path: path))
    print("connected") // called
} catch {
    print(error) // not called
    return
}

var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
services.register(databases)
```

In the database, I have a table called `posts`, that I want to query and return all entries from:

[image: database table]

This is the `Post` implementation inside */Sources/App/Models/*:

```
final class Post: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var title: String
    var body: String

    init(id: Int? = nil, title: String, body: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }
}
extension Post: SQLiteModel, Migration, Parameter { }
```

I have also added the migration in `configure.swift`:

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Post.self, database: .sqlite)
services.register(migrations)
```

In `routes.swift`, I define the `posts` route as follows:

```
router.get("posts") { req in
    return Post.query(on: req).all()
}
```

Now, when calling `localhost:8080/posts`, I get:

```
[]
```

Have I not properly connected the database?
Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the table name generated by fluent is different than your db table name as Fluent generate the table with name same as the `Model` class name. In your case `Post`.

Add static property `entity` in your model class `Post` to define a custom table name.

like this:

```
public static var entity: String {
    return "posts"
}
```